# Optimize the SQLite select statement to run a lot faster

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

This the Query I want to optimize, it seems to take 30 seconds or so to run on a database around 1.7GB with about 1.5million Rows in the PepTargetEntity and the TargetMatchEntity and only thousands in the Customer Table and SearchEntity Table. I expect such a simple statement to take milliseconds to complete.

There are indexes on :

- Customer(SearchId)
- PepTargetEntity(CustomerId)
- TargetMatchEntity(CustomerId)

If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT  CustomerId, Rank, PepId, TargetId, FalsePositive   
FROM (SELECT  T.CustomerId, T.Rank, T.Id AS PepId, NULL AS TargetId, T.FalsePositive, C.Surname, C.Firstname FROM PepTargetEntity T      
INNER JOIN Customer C ON T.CustomerId= C.Id         
WHERE c.SearchId = 3265 OR 3270 = 0

UNION

SELECT  T.CustomerId, T.Rank, Null AS PepId, T.Id AS TargetId, T.FalsePositive, C.Surname, C.Firstname 
FROM TargetmATCHEntity T
INNER JOIN Customer C ON T.CustomerId= C.Id  
WHERE c.SearchId = 3265 OR 3270 = 0)     
ORDER BY Surname ASC,FirstName ASC,Rank DESC   
LIMIT 50   
OFFSET 0
```

Comment: You're missing at least one closing paren in the code you posted.  Also, not sure what `OR 3270 = 0` means, but `OR` is frequently non-optimizable and may well be forcing SQLite to perform table scans.

Comment: why using sub query for the first element of union `FROM (SELECT`

Comment: Also, you have different numbers of columns in the two `SELECT`s that you're trying to `UNION` together.  If the two `SELECT`s return guaranteed disjoint sets you should change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.

Comment: You have all been very helpful and I have re organised my query as you have suggested and it runs in 15ms, so thank you all very much